# Is it possible to store an array of bytes (so something like bytes[])?

Tags: solidity, bytes

#### Edit

The original question below seems to work as expected. The issue happens with the call return data is empty. When the `response` is nothing, the code below fails.

The following works, **but is there a better way to do it**?

```
bytes[] memory val;
for(uint i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
    (, bytes memory response) = addr.call.value(_value[i])(_data);
    if (response.length != 0) {
        val[i] = response;
    }
}
```

---

I am unable to figure out how to store an array of `bytes`. I understand that `bytes` is an array of `byte1`s, but I want to be able to store multiple `bytes` in an array? So ideally, I would be able to define `bytes[]`, where each member of that array is a new `bytes`.

Some example code (which is not working) is:

```
bytes[] memory val;
for(uint i = 0; i < _value.length; i++) {
    (, bytes memory response) = addr.call.value(_value[i])(_data);
    val[i] = response;
}
```

This is reverting on `val[i] = response;`. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Don't you feel that there's something a bit odd (to say the least) with `val[i] = response`? The LHS and RHS are not even of the same type (let alone the fact that you're trying to set each entry in the output array to be equal to the input array).

Comment: I am adding a quick update and would love your opinion.

Comment: Also, it looks like you should be using `_value.length`, not `item.length` (what are these two variables anyway?).

Comment: "reverting" or "not compiling"?

Comment: If "reverting", then please share your execution (or testing) code. What transaction were you trying to execute? Also, there are several undefined symbols in your code, please provide a minimal working example.

Comment: I have updated the question. Yes, it was meant to be `_value.length`. That was a bad copy/paste error. It was `reverting` (it was compiling just fine).

Comment: You now have `_value` and `value` in your code!!!

Comment: Fixed again! Sorry.

Comment: You did not answer the question - "reverting" or "not compiling"? And if "reverting", then please follow the instructions in the comment which follows that question.

Comment: It is reverting.

Comment: **If "reverting", then please share your execution (or testing) code. What transaction were you trying to execute?**

Answer (score 1):

You should by the least add another internal `for` loop in your code.

Something like this:

```
bytes[] memory val = new bytes[](_value.length);
for (uint i = 0; i < _value.length; i++) {
    (bool success, bytes memory response) = addr.call.value(_value[i])(_data);
    require(success, "call failed");
    val[i] = new bytes(response.length);
    for (uint j = 0; j < response.length; j++) {
        val[i][j] = response[j];
    }
}
```